# Knockout.js What is the correct way to reference $parent on js file?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, viewmodel

I am new on Knockout.js, especially on how to use it in the Magento way.

I create a custom ViewModel with a js file called **storepickup-select.js** and an HTML template called **storepickup-select.html**.

I override **Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping** on a custom **shipping.j**s file on my custom module. In this file, I added two functions: **selectedCarrierCode** and **saveStoreAddress**.

When I call **selectedCarrierCode** on **storepickup-select.html** using the **$parent** variable, it works fine and without any problem:

```
<form class="form form-shipping-storepickup" id="co-storepickup-form" data-bind="visible: $parent.selectedCarrierCode()">
...
</form>
```

But when I tried to call **saveStoreAddress** from **storepickup-select.js**, it throws me an error:

```
selectStore: function(){
    ...                            
    $parent.saveStoreAddress(addresData);
    ...
}
```

> ReferenceError: $parent is not defined

I tried some other options:

```
parent 
this.parent
this.$parent
```

But it doesn´t work. Why I can use $**parent** on HTML file but I can´t use it on js file? And, what is the better way to call **saveStoreAddress** from js file?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I added my js files:

**shipping.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'uiRegistry',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service'
], function (
    $,
    _,
    Component,
    ko,
    customer,
    addressList,
    addressConverter,
    quote,
    createShippingAddress,
    selectShippingAddress,
    shippingRatesValidator,
    formPopUpState,
    shippingService,
    selectShippingMethodAction,
    rateRegistry,
    setShippingInformationAction,
    stepNavigator,
    modal,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    checkoutData,
    registry,
    $t
) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        selectShippingMethod: function (shippingMethod) {
            selectShippingMethodAction(shippingMethod);
            checkoutData.setSelectedShippingRate(shippingMethod.carrier_code + '_' + shippingMethod.method_code);

            return true;
        },

        selectedCarrierCode: ko.computed(function() {
          var method = quote.shippingMethod();
          var selectedCarrierCode = (method != null) ? method.carrier_code : null;
          return selectedCarrierCode;
        }),

        saveStoreAddress: function (addressData) {
          addressData['save_in_address_book'] = 0;
          console.log(addressData);
          newShippingAddress = createShippingAddress(addressData);
          selectShippingAddress(newShippingAddress);
          checkoutData.setSelectedShippingAddress(newShippingAddress.getKey());
          checkoutData.setNewCustomerShippingAddress($.extend(true, {}, addressData));
          //this.getPopUp().closeModal();
          this.isNewAddressAdded(true);
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
      return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

**storepickup-select.js**

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'mage/url',
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, ko, url, Component, quote) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Morwi_Checkout/checkout/shipping-address/storepickup-select.html'
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            initialize: function (){
              this._super();
              this.bindAvailableStores();
              this.bindSelectedStore();
            },

            storeDetailUrl: ko.observable(),

            availableStores: ko.observableArray([]),

            storeAddress: [],

            selectedStore: ko.observable(),

            bindAvailableStores: function(){
              console.log('bindAvailableStores');
              var element = this;

              $.ajax({
                url: url.build('recogertienda/stores/get'),
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                async: false,
                success: function(response){
                  element.setAvailableStores(response)

                  for(var index in response){
                    element.storeAddress[response[index].id] = response[index].address;
                  }

                  console.log(element.storeAddress);
                }
              });
            },

            bindSelectedStore: function(){
              console.log('bindSelectedStore');
              var element = this;

              $.ajax({
                url: url.build('recogertienda/stores/selected'),
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                async: false,
                success: function(response){
                  if(response.id != 0){
                    element.setSelectedStore(response.id);
                  }
                  else{
                    element.setSelectedStore('');
                  }

                  element.selectStore();
                }
              });
            },

            setAvailableStores(data){
              this.availableStores(data);
            },

            setSelectedStore(data){
              this.selectedStore(data);
            },

            selectStore: function(){
              if((typeof this.selectedStore() !== 'undefined') && (this.selectedStore() != '')){
                this.storeDetailUrl(url.build('storelocator/index/view/id/' + this.selectedStore().toString()));

                $parent.saveStoreAddress(this.storeAddress[this.selectedStore()]);
              }
              else{
                this.storeDetailUrl(url.build('storelocator'));
              }
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: where `saveStoreAddress` function define?

Comment: @RakeshVarma on shipping.js the same file of **selectedCarrierCode()**

Comment: Update your js file in question

Comment: But I mentioned it on my question: "I override Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping on a custom shipping.js file on my custom module. In this file, I added two functions: selectedCarrierCode and saveStoreAddress."

Comment: @RakeshVarma sorry, I understand now. I added the two js files to my question.

Comment: add `saveStoreAddress` in your storepickup-select.js file it will still work

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call $parent in js, just call your function directly using `this.functionName()`.

**EDIT** (Some context) :

> $parent: This is the view model object in the parent context, the one
>   immeditely outside the current context.

You call `$parent` in your case  to refer to js file associated with HTML template in `/js/view/..` i.e the view model.

Comment: Hi, I tried calling this.saveStoreAddress, but it throws me: **TypeError: this.saveStoreAddress is not a function**

Comment: Is the function located in the js file you're calling from?
If not, mention where you're calling the function and where is the function located

Comment: selectedCarrierCode and saveStoreAddress are defined on shipping.js. I called $parent.selectedCarrierCode on storepickup-select.html and works fine, but when I call $parent.saveStoreAddress on storepickup-select.js it throws me the error.

Comment: storepickup-select.html must is associated to shipping.js as a template that's why it is able to call the function from it, same cannot be done in  storepickup-select.js .

Comment: storepickup-select.htm is associate to storepickup-select.js by defaults: {
                template: 'Morwi_Checkout/checkout/shipping-address/storepickup-select.html'
            }. I added the two js files to my question.

Comment: Please post the html file too.

Answer (score 1):

Yo need to add dependecy for shipping.js in your storepickup-select.js to access its functions. Try doing this in storepickup-select.js :

```
define([
    <!-- Other dependencies -->,
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping' <!-- shipping.js path -->
], function (customShipping) {

    bindAvailableStores: function(){
    <!-- you can use this code to access the methods defined in shipping.js. -->
     customShipping.selectedCarrierCode();

}
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it throws me a error: "step code 'shipping' already registered in step navigator" I think because it run the initialize of shipping.js twice: